# agregar css externo en genexus

Tags: genexus

Estoy utilizando Genexus 15.

Quiero saber por que no puedo agregar mi `.css` en el código de mi web panel en genexus lo primero que hice fue agregar un web panel y luego inserte un `html`, ahi coloque el código de `html` y luego cree este evento en el web panel:

```
Event Start
Form.HeaderRawHTML = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Models\prueba de diseño\estilos2.css">'
Endevent
```

Según este evento podria llamar mi `.css` por que genexus trabaja el `html` solo en `body` entonces por medio de este evento agrego esa parte al `head` 
no sé que puede estar resultando mal por que el archivo está en esa ruta y cuando miro el diseño dentro de genexus si hace como que lo referencia pero al momento de compilarlo y cuando corre en el navegador solo me aparece el `html` sin nada de `css`

Comment: Creo que no deberías usar una ruta a un archivo local... El .css debería estar en tu _web server_ o en alguna URL que se pueda acceder desde el navegador.

Comment: soy nuevo en Genexus y estamos trabajando de manera local nose como hacer la solucion que me diste, si me dieras los pasos de como colocarlo en url te agradeceria mucho

Comment: No es un tema de GeneXus... Si estás desarrollando una aplicación web, tiene que estar "hosteada" en algún _web server_. En ese mismo lugar puedes poner el .css y cambiar el `href` para que referencie al archivo sin la ruta.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si será demasiado tarde (muy probable)

```
Event Start
Form.HeaderRawHTML = '[link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos2.css">'
Endevent
```

El archivo estilos2.css debe estar en la carpeta web de tu modelo. O una carpeta dentro de web.
Por ejemplo (si estás en .NET):

**E:\ModelsGX\TuModelo\CSharpModel\web**

**o  E:\ModelsGX\TuModelo\CSharpModel\web\TuCarpetaConCss**
En este último caso:

```
Form.HeaderRawHTML = '[link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TuCarpetaConCss\estilos2.css">'
```

Saludos